# Is it possible to change logo per category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

My website has four categories and I have four different color of website's logo. How can I load the different logo file per category(considering their sub and products)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento adds **specific css-classes** to the body depending on the **category**.

For example in the [demo-store](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/) you will see the following body-classes:

Category Men:

```
<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath-men-html category-men">
```

Category Accessories:

```
<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath-accessories-html category-accessories">
```

You could **set the logo via CSS background** depending on the `category` or `categorypath` class:

```
.category-men .logo {
    background-image: url("logo-men.png");
}

.category-accessories .logo {
     background-image: url("logo-accessories.png");
}
```